# Protobuf oneof fields with enum encoding

Tags: python, json, enums, type-conversion, protocol-buffers

I have a Protobuf definition as follows:

```
MyMessage {
  oneof my_oneof {
     EnumA a = 1;
     EnumB b = 2;
  }
}

enum EnumA {
ENUMA_UNSPECIFIED = 0;
FOO = 1;
BAR = 2;
}

enum EnumB {
ENUMB_UNSPECIFIED = 0;
FOOB = 1;
BARB = 2;
}
```

I set the `a` field of the proto message as follows:

```
MyMessage test;
test.a = EnumA.Value("FOO")
```

I want to read test.a and compare it with a value read from a json string:

```
{'message_enumA': "FOO"}
```

So, I want to do:

```
import json


json_dict = json.load({'message_enumA': "FOO"})
getattr(test, test.WhichOneof("my_oneof")) in json_dict.values()
```

The above code returns `False` because `getattr` returns an integer `1` corresponding to the enum in `EnumA`. I cannot do `test.a = EnumA.Name(1)` because `a` is defined as an int field internally.

I can of course wrap the `getattr(...)` call around `EnumA.Name()`. But that kind of defeats the purpose of Oneof. Is there a different way to do this?